# JAVA Get runnable object in thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using this standard constructor:

```
   new Thread(myRunnable);
```

where myRunnable is custom object with Runnable interface.

During the thread process I need to access to that runnable object (to tell the process status and progress), how can I do?

If my object would be a Thread I would use:

```
   (MyThread) Thread.getCurrentThread()
```

but with runnable passed as parameter I can not get that.

**EDIT**

This is my code structure:

```
public abstract class ProgressThread{
    private float progress;     //... progress getter, setter...    
}

public class MyRunnable extends ProgressThread implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        //starting processes...
        Job1 j1=new Job1().do();
        Job1 j2=new Job2().do();
    }

    private class Job1(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            // do something
            float progress=i/10;
            // set job progress in thread
            Thread.getCurrentThread().getRUNNABLE().setProgress(progress);
        }
    }

}
```

This is why i need getRUNNABLE() method (or a workaround!).
Thanks.

Comment: How about using `this`? (or passing it as an argument to the other objects needing access to the runnable)?

Comment: I add some code to better explain my trouble... thanks

Answer (score 6):

Just keep the reference to the runnable so you can access it when needed

```
Runnable myRunnable = ...
new Thread(myRunnable).start();

// do what you wish with the runnable
myRunnable.foo();
```

Comment: I understand I did not explain very well. I add some code to explain why i need a reference to runnable by thread.